# How does this summation work and what does it evaluate to?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

The first one suggests i begins at j? I’m having a hard time wrapping my head around i = j

$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=j}^n {n \choose i} {i \choose j}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It's always a good idea to start by writing out the first few terms. If we take just the inner sum, we have
$$
\sum_{i=j}^n {n \choose i} {i \choose j}
=
{n \choose j} {j \choose j} + 
{n \choose j+1} {j+1 \choose j} + 
{n \choose j+2} {j+2 \choose j} + \ldots + 
{n \choose n} {n \choose j}
$$

Comment: This summation is the same as $\sum_{0\leq j\leq i\leq n}$ if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using binomial expansion twice, we have:
\begin{align}
(1+(1+1))^n&=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}(1+1)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}\sum_{j=0}^{i}{i\choose j}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{i}{n \choose i}{i\choose j}
\end{align}
We notice that the summation takes values where $0\leq j\leq i\leq n$, which is the same as:
$$\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=j}^{n}{n \choose i}{i\choose j}=3^n$$

Proof by counting:

The ways to apply $3$ colors $r,g,b$ to $n$ objects. $j$ counts how many $r$ we have, $i$ counts how many $r$ and $g$ we have, thus $i$ starts from $j$, ends at $n$. Then $i\choose j$ is the ways to choose the $r$ out of $r$ and $g$ piles, and $n\choose i$ is the way to choose $r$ and $g$ pile out of all. The total ways should be $3^n$.